# HCF of given numbers

Tags: algorithm

whats the logic for calculating HCF of given numbers?

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to calculate the highest common factor, more commonly called the greatest common divisor, is [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

If you want to calculate the HCF of more than two numbers, say *i*<sub>1</sub>, *i*<sub>2</sub>, *i*<sub>3</sub>, ..., *i*<sub>n</sub>, one algorithm is:

```
res = gcd(i[1], i[2])
for j = 3..n do
    res = gcd(res, i[j])
end
return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) in C++:

```
unsigned int hcf(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
   if (b == 0) {
      return a;
   } else {
      return hcf(b, a % b);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster and shorter code for GCD

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while(b) b ^= a ^= b ^= a %= b;
return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to calculate the H.C.F of two integers
If you have any problem comment your query, feel free to ask

```
 import java.util.*;
class ABC{
      int HCF(int a,int b){
        int c;
        int d;
        c=a%b;
        if(c==0)    
            return b;
        else 
            return HCF(b,c);
     }

     public static void main(String[]args){
        int a,b;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        a= sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        b=sc.nextInt();
        ABC obj= new ABC();

        if(b>a)
            System.out.println("Wrong Input the first number must be larger than the    second one");


        else
            System.out.println("The H.C.F of "+a+" and "+b+" is: "+obj.HCF(a,b));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way, it will work no matter the order of the input:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a, b;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
    b = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The H.C.F of " + a + " and " + b + " is: " + HCF(a,b));
}

private static int HCF(int a, int b) {

    int c;
    if (a > b) {
        c = a % b;
        if (c == 0)
            return b;
        else
            return HCF(b, c);
    } else {
        c = b % a;
        if (c == 0)
            return a;
        else
            return HCF(a, c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(b):
    a, b = b, a % b
print("HCF/GCD is:",a)
```

This would give answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)